# Listas não carregam junto ao model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Meu model:

```
public class Grupo: ModelBase
  {
    public Grupo()
    {
      this.Itens = new List<Item>();
    }

    public Grupo(string nome): this()
    {
      this.Nome = nome;
    }

    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Itens { get; set; }

  }
```

Meu repository:

```
public virtual T BuscaPorId(int id)
{
  return _dbSet.Find(id);
}
```

E meu metodo na minha classe Service

```
public Grupo BuscarPorId(int id)
{
  return grupoRepository.BuscaPorId(id);
}
```

Quando eu chamo no controller ele vem as listas que estão no "Grupo"

```
public ActionResult Editar(int Id)
{
  if (Id == null)
  {
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
  }
  Grupo grupo = grupoService.BuscarPorId(Id);
```

Mas quando eu clico em salvar e passo para o meu Serviço que chama o meu método `this.BuscarPorId`, exatamente o mesmo método que chamei no controller, aqui ele não carrega as listas, apenas os dados "Nome,Id"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Find` não garante carga de entidades dependentes aqui:

```
public virtual T BuscaPorId(int id)
{
    return _dbSet.Find(id);
}
```

Faça a carga explícita dos ítens para garantir que eles retornem como desejado:

```
public virtual T BuscaPorId(int id)
{
    return _dbSet.Include(g => g.Itens).SingleOrDefault(g => g.Id == id);
}
```